# Как вернуть данные из РНР в формате JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Много всего прочитал о AJAX запросах и как они работают вроде бы понял, но как это применить никак не догадаюсь.

В общем, в getSQL.php есть переменная в которую с сервера приходит массив всех товаров `$result = R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM product' );`

А в cart.js в переменной `cartId` хранится массив ид тех товаров, которые мне нужны.
Как из `result` вытащить описания, цену, размер и тд по ID и записать это в переменную в JS?

Comment: Необходим код. Вы используйте паттерны проектирования?

Comment: @doox911 Код чего именно вам нужен? И про паттерны не совсем понял, можно поподробней?Если вы про CMS, то нет, не использую, а R:: это в RedBeanPHP супер объект такой)

Answer (score -1):

На стороне клиента (в браузере) Вам необходимо выполнить запрос к *getSQL.php*, который должен вернуть список товаров. Де-факто AJAX работает с форматом JSON. Для нужно преобразовать переменную `$result` в JSON формат:

```
$result = R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM product' );
// Помните, что функцию header() можно вызывать 
// только если клиенту еще не передавались данные, 
// т.е. она должна идти первой в выводе, 
// перед ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML-тегов, пустых строк и т.п.
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

```
$.getJSON('getSQL.php', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

#### Ссылки по теме

- [PHP функция json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)
- [PHP функция header](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)
- [Ajax запрос JSON-данных](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_JSON-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: Чудовищный ответ. Гугль выдаёт *это* первой ссылкой по запросу "Как сделать аякс запрос"... а внутри - какой-то говнокод с redbean

Comment: @Ипатьев где конструктивная критика коллега? Вы можете добавить свой ответ, комментарий, в котором Вы укажете на мои упущения... Чем Вам показался ответ чудовищным? И где именно попахивает код?