# Принять данные AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Всем привет!
есть вот такое вот echo с данными

```
echo(json_encode(['success' => true, 'paymentUrl' => $create['url'] . '?OrderID=' . $create['id'] . '&SessionID=' . $create['session']], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

его нужно принять в другом файле через AJAX (только принять чтобы обработать те данные которые там формируются). С AJAX я знаком второй день, подскажите плз как правильно принять вот такое вот echo?

Comment: Также как и любые другие эхи из скриптов - в `success`-колбеке ajax-вызова.

Comment: не могли бы вы написать пример к данной ситуации, потому что повторюсь, всего 2 дня вижу эти конструкции(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/928174/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-ajax-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81

Comment: ознакомился, все равно не понятно, очень прошу показать на примере